# Jasper Report Studio - create/edit a report FILE without using/creating a project?

Tags: spring-boot, github, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I experiment with Spring Boot projects on Github etc. In most projects I have only 1 or 2 Jasper Report reports. Working with Jasper Spring Studio is a good practice.

I would like to edit 1 Jasper Report in a Spring subfolder without using the the extra Jasper Report **project** stuff. Is this possible?

If not possible, using workspaces is of course possible. I see a few disadvantages:

- Switching work spaces for different projects independent of Github is not practical.
- I also see that folders and files are created like MetaData and MyReports. I would like to have Github as clean as possible
- When needed another person should be able to easily change that 1 report.
- I don't want other persons to have a Jasper Report Studio project file outside the Git project folder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each team member could create once a local JasperReport project in any folder. You can then add (once) a folder, with the specific file. Use the option “DYNAMIC”.